# Coherence Cache and WPF

Tags: wpf

A couple of very basis ques:

1) I want to try WPF and coherence cache. I do not have much idea about coherence, but have heard that it has some event mechanism that can tell WPF if some underlying data has changed. So using that, we should be able to update the view whenever the underlying data changes, correct?

2) For that to happen, should all the interaction with Coherence be running on a separate thread so that we can read the events coming in or will it work on the main UI thread?

Comment: Do you mean DataBinding?

Comment: Yes. I effectively want to display any changes that happened in Coherence Cache and sent to me as an event instantly on the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, Oracle Coherence may be overkill for this problem. Coherence is really good when you have multiple servers that need to keep data in sync, and/or when you have lots of clients that need to connect in to live data. It sounds like you might have that second use case, but it's unclear.

Coherence has several very handy abilities for clients that need to keep their data up to date. For example, a client can create a Continuous Query Cache, which means that the data result for that query gets cached in RAM on the client, and then whenever any other client (or any server) changes that data, it is automatically updated in the RAM of that client. Then if the UI needs to be updated, it is very simple, because the UI can sign up for the event when that data in RAM changes. This is used in applications like trading systems for financial services companies.

One more thing you *might* be asking about is when data in the database changes. There is a Coherence feature called Coherence Hot Cache, which uses event data that flows from the database (using Oracle GoldenGate technology) to update the cache servers, which in turn update the various Continuous Query caches and push out events (as described above). So basically, you can have data pushed all the way form a database change up into the GUIs that people are looking at. It's pretty cool stuff :)

*(For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.)*

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is the answer. There are data bindings, events, notification.